# In which order the SQL queries will execute

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql

I have a query as given below

```
select 
    student_id, student_name, student_total 
from 
    student 
where 
    (student_name like %a% and student_total > 400) 
    or student_rank < 10
```

In SQL engine, how it will execute this query. whether the condition will check from right to left or left to right?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Stuff like this is **highly dependent** on the **concrete database** you're using. Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Does it matter to you, as long as the answer is correct and delivered fast enough?

Comment: Also, it depends on indexes and table data.

Comment: I just want to know the query execute pattern here. For example i have two where condition with AND operator. If the first condition return 1000 records and second condition return 10 records, then definitely there will be some performance issue based on this condition. So i would like to get the execution behavior.

Comment: @VijayThayalan Most databases perform rather advanced query optimization techniques, that depends on not only how your table look like and what indexes your table have, but also what data you already have in your tables, so this is rather impossible to answer in the general case. You better ask your particular database server to show the [query plan](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-explain.html) , which is the closes you'll get to the answer you want.

Comment: @nos At a given point in time, of course. The same query might generate wildly different execution plans next month, or even next second. But at least it's *some* information about what's happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

You don't know, and you must not depend on the answer.

The execution planner is the one that handles preparing the actual step-by-step plan of executing the query. This will tend to change with indices, statistics and such. It might very well evaluate the `like` first on a table with 100 rows, but the `student_rank < 10` first on a table with 10 million rows and an index on `student_rank`. And if the statistics are right and you have an index on `student_total`, it might filter based on `student_total` *first*, even though it's deep inside the filter expression tree. The answer can also change with new versions of the engine, and possibly even with upgrades and updates to the server (e.g. the amount of memory available, total network and CPU load, ...)

Why do you care? It's the DB engine's problem to solve. And given that you're doing a `like '%something%'`, it will most likely put that as the last condition pretty much always - as long as there's an index it can use for `student_rank`.

The fact that there's *no* definite order of execution also has implications that might surprise you. For example, if you have a function that throws an exception / error if it's passed a value of `null`, doing `(SomeColumn is not null and MyFunction(SomeColumn))` is *not* safe - it will still throw the exception / error for any row with a `null` value in `SomeColumn`.

Only the most primitive (barely-)SQL databases have any notion of a fixed order of execution. The thing you should focus on is making the SQL readable first and foremost. Performance tweaks must always be precisely documented, along with tests to replicate the intented behaviour etc., because they are extremely fragile. Before adding index hints, make sure your indices are properly maintained, with up-to-date statistics, low fragmentation, good coverage etc. etc. When the execution planner produces sub-optimal execution plans, it's almost always your fault (and very rarely, a subtle bug in the engine, or a known limitation) - either by trying performance tricks in the SQL, or by having no DBA taking care of the maintenance.